# How to define hierarchy routing in angular modules

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

As you know to create hierarchy routing in angular we define a list like bellow:

```
const crisisCenterRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'crisis-center',
    component: CrisisCenterComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: CrisisListComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: ':id',
            component: CrisisDetailComponent
          },
          {
            path: '',
            component: CrisisCenterHomeComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Also we use router-outlet in each level of components' template as a container in order to render the corresponding component.

Assume that each level of routing has defined in individual modules and all modules imported in parent module.

How can define above routing hierarchy as well as use multiple router-outlet in each modules?

Comment: If a route with an empty path has no child routes and no redirect, it should have `pathMatch: 'full'`. Your `CrisisCenterHomeComponent` always matches and `CrisisDetailComponent` never matches.

Comment: the problem is loading children which is defined in other module.

Comment: I know, I didn't add it as answer. You should still be aware that `path: ''` needs some special considerations. It matches always if `pathMatch: 'full'` isn't added, and then search continues with its child routes, not with siblings.

Comment: With child routes in modules you usually use https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration

Comment: do you want to have only logical separation? or functional? because all non-lazy modules and their routes are merged into one module. read [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f)

Comment: lazy or not lazy is not matter. I have parent module in which router-outlet there is in main.component. Also many modules exist and imported in parent module. In all of them there is router-outlet. Can u provide me practical sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using lazy-lading to define hierarchy routing in a project in which all components are separated to individual's modules, but it didn't work. I had wrotten Webpack configuration by myself to create bundles. The problem was I didn't use this loader in Webpack:

```
angular-router-loader
```

[As described](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-router-loader), angular-router-loader must be added to typescript loader.